# OpenGL VBO Segfault when calling glDrawArrays()

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I've been trying to get VBOs working in my latest project and the program segfaults when I try to call glDrawArrays.

Generating the VBO

```
bool Renderer::init()
{
GLfloat verticies[]=
{0,0,
 0,32,
 32,32,
 32, 0};

glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboTest);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboTest);

glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(verticies), verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

And then the rendering the VBO

```
void Renderer::renderScene()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboTest);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glLoadIdentity();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you using? Are you using shaders? I'm not sure how OpenGL works when you try rendering (X,Y) coordinates as vertices, try adding a Z coordinate and change glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0); to glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

Comment: Are you sure segfault happens in `DrawArrays`? What is stacktrace for crash?

Comment: Actually I figured it out and it was quite a stupid error, I was using SDL_GL_GetProcAddress to load the functions, but I had the prototypes in my main file, but in the renderer header I defined GL_EXT_PROTOTYPES so it was trying to access them through the glext function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a stupid arbitrary error. I loaded the functions using SDL_GL_GetProcAddress, but then in the header for the renderer class defined GL_EXT_PROTOTYPES instead of re-prototyping the functions.